# Finite expectation (variance) in Markov inequality and Chebyshev inequality?

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider a random variable $X$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

(1) If $\exists$ $E_{\mathbb{P}}(X)$, then
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X|\geq t)\leq \frac{E_{\mathbb{P}}(|X|)}{t}
$$

$\forall t>0$ (Markov inequality). Question: do we need $|E_{\mathbb{P}}(X)|<\infty$ to show the result? I think the answer is no, but I would like a confirmation.

(2) If $\exists$ $Var(X)$, then
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X-E_{\mathbb{P}}(X)|\geq t)\leq \frac{Var(X)}{t^2}
$$

$\forall t>0$ (Chebychev inequality). Question: do we need $Var(X)<\infty$ to show the result? I think the answer is no, but, again, I would like a confirmation.

Comment: If $|E_{\Bbb P}(X)|=+\infty$ or $Var(X)=+\infty$ then both RHS bounds are equal to $+\infty$ and therefore hold trivially. So, the only interesting case is when these are $<+\infty$.

Comment: You need $|E_{\mathbb{P}}(X)|$ finite for $Var(X)$ to be defined (even if $+\infty$) for use in (2)